# Could I integrate and deploy K2 blackpearl workflow engine for Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, workflow, sharepoint-workflow, k2

I have one of the biggest Government agencies looking for new Portal based on Drupal, and they have a lot of workflows that need to be built via K2 workflow.

Could I integrate and deploy K2 blackpearl workflow engine for Drupal?

Does K2 blackpearl support that? Can Drupal handle this to be front-end for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an appropriate answer, you would need to defined what you mean by 'integrate'.
I am not familiar with what Drupal does or not but as far as I know, this is a CMS.
So let me ask and answer a few questions, hopefully, one of the points is what you are looking for.

**Can we integrate K2 forms into another product such as Drupal?**
Yes, you can use iFrames to do that.

**Could K2 access data from Drupal?**
Yes. I am assuming Drupal stores its data in a MySQL server. There is a service broker from the community for MySQL. It would allow you reading and writting back data from/to the Drupal database.

**Could drupal start processes?**
No really, but you could a form using SmartForms that could do that and integrate that into an iFrame.

**Can you access the blackpearl data from a third party product?**
This one is more complicated than the others. Theorically, you could use the 2 available APIs (K2Services to the processes and tasks mainly and the SmartObject Services to access any SmartObject) to access K2 data from Javascript for example. The problem is as far as I know is that K2 does not handle (or not properly) cross origin requests (CORS).

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: On the point that could drupal start processes in K2, if drupal support invoking webservice call. You can start K2 processes via the webservice call from Durpal. But you will have to fill in some parameters such as K2 process name.

Comment: That´s right. If you want to start processes from the WebServices that K2 offers, you will have 2 options. The simpler option is to use the GET method of the API which mainly requires the process name and the folio. The folio can be any string. If you need to pass more such as Data fields, you will have to use the POST request of the API. You can then provide Data fields, priority, severity, folio, ....